# Efficient way to convert datetime object to string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I'm converting a datetime column (referred to as `DATE`) in my Pandas dataframe `df` to a string of the form `'Ymd'` (e.g. `'20191201'` for December 1st 2019). My current way of doing that is:

```
import datetime as dt

df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y%m%d'))
```

But this is surprisingly inefficient and slow when run on large dataframes with millions of rows. Is there a more efficient alternative I am not seeing? That would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')` ...?

Comment: Why you need to change the datetime object with a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pandas` you do not need apply

```
df['Date']=df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```